# What run configuration should I choose to run my scala progs on Eclipse

Tags: scala

As of now, I'm running my progs on eclipse-scala interpreter, but it is asking me when I click the run button to choose run configuration like eclipse application, java applet, java application,junit, junit plugin test, maven build, scala application, scala intrepreter, scala test etc.. Please tell me which one I should choose to eirk the progs in e-book and also how to configure it. I'm a beginner.

Comment: Make sure if you are extending `App` that it is an `object` and not a `class`. Otherwise scalaide wont recognize it as a runnable program.

Comment: Can you be more precise because I'm not able to catch up with you. See I started off running programs in the ebook upto some 75 pages. I run the program in class, but how to print the output on console and not interpreter.

Comment: For ScalaIDE (Eclipse) to know how to run your program it has to be an `object` and it has to either have a `main(args: Array(String))` or extend the trait `App`. If you do one of those things, it will let you run it as a "Scala Application". Look at the example at the top of this page: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.App